# Oddity of explicitly marking dependent names as typename and template

Tags: c++, templates, types, typename

Please have a look at this code snippet:

```
template<typename T>
struct s {
    template<int Index>
    using type_alias = s<typename T::template identifier<Index>::type>;
};
```

This is compiling but only due to the explicit `typename` and `template` 'markers' for the dependent names at the `s::type_alias` type-alias.

I wonder about the following two things:

1. Why do I need to explicitly mark `T` as `typename`? It is after all *not* a dependent name, but instead exactly a `typename` as specified in the template parameter list of `s`.
2. Why can I only (optionally) mark `type` as `template` (i. e. `s<typename T::template identifier<Index>::template type>`) but not as `typename`? Ultimately, it *is* used as a `typename` template argument for `s`, so it *does* have to be a `typename`.

`MSVC 19.25.28614 for x64` with `/std:c++latest` was used if that is relevant.

---

PS: Title and question are very specialized in its original version so don't hesitate to edit it if you find a way to generalize it somehow.

Comment: `typename` doen't mark `T` as a type - it marks `type`, the last component in the fully qualified name. `type` is too a dependent name. As to why you can't put `typename` directly in front of `type` - well, because the syntax doesn't allow it. `typename` goes before the full name, not before individual components (in contrast with `template`).

Comment: For later visitors: Comment and answer helped me to find the relevant cppreference pages explaining this circumstance: [typename](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/dependent_name#The_typename_disambiguator_for_dependent_names) and [template](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/dependent_name#The_template_disambiguator_for_dependent_names) (two consecutive sections at time of writing).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In the syntax:

```
typename T::template identifier<Index>::type
```

the `typename` keyword isn't saying that `T` is a type - it's saying that the whole thing `T::template identifier<Index>::type` is a type. When it's not introducing a template parameter, `typename` always comes before a *qualified-id*, something containing at least one `::` token like `A::B::C`, and says that the last name in that chain of names and `::` tokens names a type.

On the other hand, the use of the `template` keyword to specify that a member name names a template always comes after a `::` or `.` or `->` token and immediately before the name which is a template.

So in this example, it's valid grammar to have `T::template identifier<Index>::template type`, but that doesn't make sense together with the preceding `typename` and the fact that `s` expects a type, not a template, as its template argument.

Comment: Thanks, that makes sense so far!

But you say having `template type` `T::template identifier<Index>::template type` *makes no sense*. I'd agree with you. However I can still use it like this and access is in instantiations. So what does it in fact mean?

Comment: It means MSVC is being strange: https://godbolt.org/z/E83z3v